# What study material required for Magento 2 Professional Developer Exam?

Tags: magento2, certification

Can anyone suggest me which pdf,tutorial or need to buy some practice test papers to the Magento 2 Professional Developer exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interactive quiz https://m2professional.dev
They add new question quite frequently

Answer (score 3):

What i suggest for learning before taking the exam are :

- Free MAGENTO 2 CERTIFIED PROFESSIONAL DEVELOPER Study Guide [Link](https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-professional-developer#.XD2Ydc9KhTY) (you can purchase the Magento 2 Certified Developer Study Group for more knowledgement)
- Magento 2 Udemy Course (has also Practice Test) [Link](https://www.udemy.com/magento-magento-2-certified-developer-exam-learn-full-course/)
- Swiftotter Study Guide [Link](https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-developer-study-guide) and Practice Test [Link](https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-developer-practice-test) (The practice test of swiftotter will help you a lot )

PS. Do not learn like a 'machine' but try to get the base components of each chapter and learn with logic if they where a case study , or a task being assigned from a client . Good Luck .

```
Magento Architecture & Customization Techniques
Request Flow Processing
Customizing Magento UI
Working with databases in Magento
Using the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) Model
Developing with Adminhtml
Customizing Catalog
Customizing Checkout Process
Sales Operations
Customer Management
```

Comment: Swiftotter practice test paper questions are for Associate or Professional Developer exam?

Comment: The link i attached https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-developer-practice-test is For Proffessional Developer exam https://d.pr/free/i/EqXmzw also the Guide.

Comment: there is written "46.5 questions per take.* 2 pools of unique questions." so will be two set of questions one set contains 45 question approx?

Comment: If you take exam for free , you have 7 questions . Approximately 46 questions per take (two unique pools of questions) . One pool has 46 , if you purchase the exam , than you will have one of the pool . Purchasing with the unlimited takes , i think you will get the same pool but with the same questions you took the test before but changing their order .

Comment: so what's your opinion on this i should go for one pool or purchase unlimited plan?

Comment: I would have take the unlimited takes for 1 month . Even that they are the same questions , its better to repeat the exam and correct the mistakes you made  on the first try (this is if you fail ;) ) and have your time to understand the question more clearly.

Comment: so how many unique question you observed was there in unlimited plan?

Comment: What do you mean with unique question ? As i said the "1 take" and "Unlitemated takes for 1 month" has the same questions , but the second option makes you take the exam more than ones.

Comment: Can you marked the Answer as useful (if it helped for you ) .

Comment: It was brutal test! I have to retry :(